# How to fetch particular record from table X joining table Y or table Z where table Y and Z has same column name with same kind of data?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, toad

I have below query where I am getting data from joining table log and equipment but b.id which is coming out of table equipment is also in another table called equipment2 with same column name. so I have to write a query where if equipment table has empty or null value on that id column then has to pull out the record joining on table  equipment2 with table log otherwise it has to join table equipment and log.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (a.LOG_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') LOG_DATE,
b.id,
a.atid,
a.l_type,
a.l_subtype,
a.eq,
a.name,
a.comments
FROM log a, (equipment b or equipment2 b)
WHERE a.eqid = b.eqid(+)
AND log_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('07/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                      AND  TO_DATE ('07/08/2070', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY a.log_date,
b.id,
a.atid,
a.l_type,
a.l_subtype,
a.eq,
a.name,
a.comments
ORDER BY b.id;
```

Comment: Is there any reference defined between those tables? This sentence sounds strange to me: `equipment table has **empty** or null value`. Also, why are there two  "equipment" tables? Do they share the same structure?

Comment: we have two equipment type in our database. let say when user submit their request they can select either type 1 equipment or type 2. both type of equipment data is coming from single table called eqdata where id(primary key) is the same but the type of equipment is different. so we stored data based on equipment type. if its equipment type 1 then it will go to equipment1 table otherwise if its equipment type 2 then it will go to equuipment2 table.

Comment: These types of problems become so much easier to avoid or resolve by using ANSI-92 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the child record will ALWAYS be in either equipment or equipment2, but never both, you could just add equipment2 with an outer join, and use NVL() to pick the not null value:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (a.LOG_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') LOG_DATE,
  nvl(b.id,b2.id),
  a.atid,
  a.l_type,
  a.l_subtype,
  a.eq,
  a.name,
  a.comments
FROM 
  log a, 
  equipment b,
  equipment2 b2
WHERE 
  a.eqid = b.eqid(+)
  AND a.eqid = b2.eqid(+)
  AND log_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('07/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                  AND  TO_DATE ('07/08/2070', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
ORDER BY 2
```

This also assumes that you're only picking a column that will not be populated with a NULL.  If, for example, equipment/equipment2 also contains a "name" column that might be null, you'd need some additional logic:

```
case when b.id is null then b2.name else b.name end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to merge the two equipment tables and just join that. Assuming the table structure is identical in equipment and equipment2 otherwise you'll want to select your specific fields of course. Otherwise...

```
 SELECT *
 INTO #equipTemp
 FROM equipment WHERE ID IS NOT NULL
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM equipment2 WHERE ID IS NOT NULL

SELECT TO_CHAR (a.LOG_DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy HH:MI:SS') LOG_DATE,
 b.id,
 a.atid,
 a.l_type,
 a.l_subtype,
 a.eq,
 a.name,
 a.comments
 FROM log a, #eqipTemp b
 WHERE a.eqid = b.eqid(+)
 AND log_date BETWEEN TO_DATE ('07/01/2013', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                  AND  TO_DATE ('07/08/2070', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
 GROPU BY...
```